# How to find values with minimal absolute values in several columns ignoring NaNs?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have the following two pandas time series (but the question is also applicable to numpy array):

```
NaN               NaN
NaN               2
NaN               1
NaN               0
NaN              -1
NaN              -2
6                -3
5                -4
4                -5
3                NaN
2                NaN
```

I would like to combine these two columns in the following way. If both columns contain `NaN`, the resulting column gets `NaN`, otherwise we get the value with the minimal absolute value.

For example in the considered case we should get:

```
 NaN
 2
 1
 0
-1
-2
-3
-4
 4
 3
 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let, `df` the dataframe with two columns, apply *conditional absolute minimum* over rows using `axis=1`

Here, `x[np.argmin(x.abs())]` checks the row index with absolute minimum and return the the original value with sign.

Also, we would need `pd.isnull(x.min())` check for `'All-NaN slice encountered` i.e when both the columns have `NaN` values.

```
In [3]: df.apply(lambda x: x.min() if pd.isnull(x.min()) else
                           x[np.argmin(x.abs())], axis=1)
Out[3]:
0    NaN
1      2
2      1
3      0
4     -1
5     -2
6     -3
7     -4
8      4
9      3
10     2
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, after reading and understanding your question and not being able to find a vectorised approach, we can define a custom function and call `apply` and pass each row.

So this will check if either column is null if so return the min value, it then compares the abs value of either column and then returns the column that has smallest abs value but the original value including sign:

```
In [269]:

def func(x):
    if pd.isnull(x.a) or pd.isnull(x.b):
        return x.min()
    elif np.abs(x.a) < np.abs(x.b):
        return x.a
    else:
        return x.b

df.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis = 1)
Out[269]:
0    NaN
1      2
2      1
3      0
4     -1
5     -2
6     -3
7     -4
8      4
9      3
10     2
dtype: float64
```

Comment: @EdChum I got consfused when I posted my initial answer too. OP meant to *get the value with the minimal absolute value.* **with the sign**